# Evaluate: $ \int_0^1 \int_y^1 e^{x^2 }dxdy$

Tags: integration

> Evaluate: $$ \int_0^1  \int_y^1 e^{x^2 }dxdy=?$$

MyTry :

$$\begin{align} \int_0^1  \big(\int_y^1 e^{x^2 }dx\big)dy=?\end{align}$$

Now what ?

$$I=\big(\int_y^1 e^{x^2 }dx\big)=?$$

Comment: Change order of integration

Comment: You might want to read http://mathinsight.org/double_integral_change_order_integration_examples, your example is there

Answer (score 7):

You have to switch the bounds of integration

$$ \int_0^1  \int_y^1 e^{x^2 }dxdy$$
$$ =\int_0^1  \int_0^x e^{x^2 }dydx$$
$$ =\int_0^1   xe^{x^2 }dx$$
$$ =1/2e^{x^2 }|^1_0$$
$$=1/2(e-1)$$